# jQuery Delaying Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delay things like the css from happening but this method wont work. Any ideas on how I can delay tasks.

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.divOne').animate({"left": "+=400px"}, "fast").delay(800).css("background-color","yellow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to stick it on the default animation (`fx`) queue, like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.divOne').animate({"left":"+=400px"}, "fast").delay(800).queue(function(n) {
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
    n(); //call next function in the queue, needed if you animate later!
  });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nUPgk/), all this does is stick it in the `fx` queue using [`.queue(function(n))`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), the `n` is the *next* function in the queue, so we're calling it, for example if you *didn't* do this and added any animation after it, it just wouldn't run, because the next function or [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) isn't called.

Comment: `n` is not actually the next function in the qeue, it is an anonymous function that calls `dequeue()`, effectively calling the next function in the queue, yes....

Comment: @gnarf - Matter of semantics I suppose, when you follow the method chain, that anonymous function *is* the next in the queue, effectively, even if not in the queue array itself, it is the *next function* for every other function in the queue :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a callback function on the animate. Once the animation is complete use a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.divOne').animate({"left": "+=400px"},"fast", function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $elem.css('background-color','yellow');
        }, 800);
    })
});
```

This might not be syntactically perfect.

Comment: Don't pass a string to setTimeout! It should look like this instead: `setTimeout(function() { $('.div.one').css('background-color','yellow') }, 800);`

Comment: I updated your answer to not use the evil `eval`ed string argument to setTimeout, and also made it store the animated element in the callback, so you don't have to hunt it down through a jQuery DOM selector again.